# I cant start React app after deploy to GCP because of missing module 'eslint/lib/formatters/stylish'

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, build-error

My React app works ok but when I deploy to Google Cloud Platform i get this error in the browser

> ./src/index.js Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module
>    'eslint/lib/formatters/stylish'
>
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

I have read many Google answers on this like [This](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3617) but no luck.

I have tried remove package-lock.json and node_modules and then run npm install, that made no difference still get the error

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "AspNetCoreReactRedux",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "primereact": "3.1.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "reactstrap": "^6.3.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  }
}
```

I think there is something wrong with the package.json but dont know what

I read that I could try:

If you haven't ejected and see this problem:

```
Remove anything with the word eslint from package.json
Remove package-lock.json and yarn.lock
Remove node_modules
Run npm install (or yarn if you use it)
```

But is that safe to do, will that not remove the eslint?

Answer (score -1):

ok i did this and now I can deploy

```
Remove anything with the word eslint from package.json
Remove package-lock.json and yarn.lock
Remove node_modules
Run npm install (or yarn if you use it)
```